# Is ethereum's protocol made in Go?

Tags: go-ethereum

I came across a repo on github https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum . Is this ethereum's official implementation? I mean is it official protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this ethereum's official implementation?

It is. (https://geth.ethereum.org/ -> *"Official Go implementation of the Ethereum protocol"*)

> I mean is it official protocol?

The protocol is defined in the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) specification. Anyone can write their own client implementation that adheres to the spec.

A list of available clients can be found here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#clients